# MIUI vs android widgets

Tags: android, layout, button, checkbox, rom

Does anybody can tell me what is apperance of default android widgets like Buttons, CheckBoxes, RadioButtons in MIUI roms?

To be precise, I want to change to MIUI rom on my SGS, but as an app developer I want to know if the basic views in 3rd party apps (like AlertDialogs, Buttons) will be the same as on stock android rom or totaly diffrent what will make dificult to design UI layouts for apps.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your Galaxy S itself is not even stock android - many of the UI widgets are already customized. You should not have any problems nonetheless with designing your app, if you follow standard UI guidelines.

Comment: I know that views for each brand are customized by manufaturer. But when I see on YouTube some sample movies from MIUI I can see that some views are strongly customized (popup sliding from top of the screen, switches like in iphone), so I'm wodering if I will place for example <CheckBox/> will it be android checkbox or an iphone switch, which is more wider etc...